# Python SQLite Delete From Where multiple values match

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to delete entries in my SQLite DB where all Values match.

So I create the entry like that:

```
    # Insert a row of data
    c.execute("insert into Database (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6))
```

And later on i will delete the exact entry by its values. I tried it like that:

```
    c.execute("delete from Database where (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            ("String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", "String6"))
```

But i get this: `OperationalError: near "values": syntax error`

How do I delete a SQLite entry with multiple values matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the full SQL condition:

```
c.execute('delete from Database where Value1=? and Value2=? and Value3=? and Value4=? and Value5=? and Value6=?',  ("String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", "String5", "String6"))
```

You can learn the full syntax [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).